# nestjs- how to define multiple types for a field in mongodb mongoose with class properties in nest

Tags: node.js, backend, nestjs

take a look in this code:

```
@prop({
    required: true,
    autopopulate: true,
    ref: Fund || Project,
  })
  organization: Ref<Fund> | Ref<Project>;
```

the property "organization" type can be Fund or Project. 
in this example when the type is "Fund" i get the object. but when the type is "Project" i get null.
I dont know nest so much and I am starter in nest. I started using it very recently.

how can i solve that problem??
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two field to achieve this, first is the reference on what model the field refers to and the second is the objectid you stored to.

**Note**: on the name at enum,

```
Class Person {
   @prop({required: true, enum: 'Fund' | 'Project'})
   which: string;

   @prop({refPath: "which"})
   organization: Ref<Fund | Project>;
}
```

For reference just check this [mongoose official docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref)

Comment: How can I assign a different name field between mongo and my code, example in a document at mongo the field name is _xyz_ (legacy), then in my app I'd like to use more descriptive name for field like _originCode_ ? Exist something like this:

`@Prop(name : 'xyz') 
originCode: string`

Comment: Public property  exported class has or is using private name 'Ref'.ts(4031) this is giving this error

Comment: This is an example of typegoose. How can we achieve this using nestjs/mongoose package? @vpdiongzon